# "fireTableChanged" event on JTable model throws exception after filtering

Tags: java, swing, jtable, thread-safety, filtering

I apply two operations on a JTable with a custom model.

First a filtering operation:

```
// rf is a RowFilter object
((DefaultRowSorter) table.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(rf);
```

Thereafter, another thread changes table column names and fires an event:

```
model.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(model, TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW));
```

But, a Runtime exception is being thrown. What could be the possible reason?

The trace is given below. Thanks.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1  at
>   java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:734)     at
>   java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)   at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
>     at
>   com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseTableHeaderUI.getHeaderRenderer(BaseTableHeaderUI.java:189)
>     at
>   com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseTableHeaderUI.paintCell(BaseTableHeaderUI.java:358)
>     at
>   com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseTableHeaderUI.paint(BaseTableHeaderUI.java:327)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)

Comment: The method ``com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseTableHeaderUI.getHeaderRenderer`` calls ``DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(-1)`` which is not going to work. Are you involved in this stacktrace with any of your classes?

Comment: "When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates."—[loc.cit.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: @f1sh No, I am not involved. However, I call `fireTableChanged` in EDT.

Comment: @trashgod I don't explicitly try to get any of the rows by index after filtering. The only operation following is renaming the column headers and firing the model change event on model.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stacktrace I would guess a bug in BaseTableHeaderUI

```
com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseTableHeaderUI.getHeaderRenderer(BaseTableHeaderUI.java:189)
```

because above that is a call to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel:

```
/**
 * Returns the <code>TableColumn</code> object for the column
 * at <code>columnIndex</code>.
 *
 * @param   columnIndex     the index of the column desired
 * @return  the <code>TableColumn</code> object for the column
 *                          at <code>columnIndex</code>
 */
public TableColumn getColumn(int columnIndex) {
    return tableColumns.elementAt(columnIndex);
}
```

Looks like BaseTableHeaderUI has problems with your two threads.
So maybe you should process all events in the same thread? My choice would be the Event-Dipatch-Thread.

Comment: thank you. I didn't get what you mean by "two threads". `fireModelChanged` call on model is called inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: must be part of (AbstractTableModel), as aside fireModelChanged can reseting all changes (JTable, rellations to its model, ColumnModel, Editor, Renderer,... ) to defaults (that came from a new models definitions), SelectionModel can ignores that

Comment: I got rid of calling `fireTableChanged`. The problem is, as @trashgod reminded, the table row index values change after applying a filter operation. Instead, I iterate over the columns by converting index values to view and then set the header values. However, I had to call `repaint` method on table header.